# How do I assign a value to a variable once?

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno, atmega

I need to assign a one-time value to two variables. 'keypressed' when the button is pressed, 'keyrelesed' when it is released. The rest of the time they should both have the value 'nokey'.When it is output, it should look like this.

```
keypressed = nokey                           //button at rest
keyrelesed = nokey

keypressed = "The value of the pressed button"     //button is pressed
keyrelesed = nokey

keypressed = nokey                           //button continues to be pressed
keyrelesed = nokey

nokey = keypressed
keyrelesed = "The value of the depressed button"     //button is released

keypressed = nokey
keyrelesed = nokey

It turns out that "The value of pressed button" = "The value of depressed button".
```

The way of accepting the value of the button.

```
 nokey = 255;
 byte keyreleased = nokey;
 byte keypressed = nokey;
 byte lastKey = keypressed;
void loop() {
int analogVal = analogRead(A0);               //read analog voltage value from pin A0
  if (analogVal < 325) keypressed = instrkey; //Correspondence of value and variable
  if (analogVal < 300) keypressed  = keyB4;
  if (analogVal < 275) keypressed  = keyA4s;
  if (analogVal < 250) keypressed  = keyA4;
  if (analogVal < 225) keypressed  = keyG4s;
  if (analogVal < 200) keypressed  = keyG4;
  if (analogVal < 175) keypressed  = keyF4s;
  if (analogVal < 150) keypressed  = keyF4;
  if (analogVal < 125) keypressed  = keyE4;
  if (analogVal < 100) keypressed  = keyD4s;
  if (analogVal < 75) keypressed  = keyD4;
  if (analogVal < 50) keypressed  = keyC4s;
  if (analogVal < 25) keypressed  = keyC4;
  if (analogVal > 1000) keypressed  = nokey;

  if (lastKey != keypressed) {               //button release detection
    keyreleased=lastKey;
    lastKey=keypressed;
  }
}
```

The "lastkey" variable does not have to be used.

I tried to explain as best I could.

Comment: Sounds you need a very simple state machine here. But the problem is not clearly stated.

Comment: Define "one time". What is "time" in your case? One clock tick? One output? Something else?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Translation error. I need the variable to always have the value 'nokey' and take the value 'keypressed' for one moment, and then, even if the button is held, return to 'nokey' again.

Comment: Again, define "moment". Where does it start and where does it end.

Comment: I understand you try to distinguish more than 10 different states by an analog value between  300 and 25 . Rather challenging.

Comment: For example "I want the value to be to be <X> at the clock cycle next to the cycle the key was pressed, and <Y> in the subsequent cycles if it is still pressed". Or "I want to sample the key in a loop, and output <X> in the iteration it was pressed, and <Y> in the subsequent iteration if it is still pressed".

Comment: In both of these case, you do whatever you want to do with the value in each cycle (print it? ), then you set it `nokey` in the end of the cycle.

Comment: After the 'keypressed' variable has been assigned an appropriate value, it is assigned a 'nokey'. In the original code, the button is detected this way.
`prevbutstatD = butstatD;
  butstatD = PIND;
  byte keypressed = nokey;
  byte keyreleased = nokey;
  if(butstatD!=prevbutstatD){
    if ( pinD0!=nokey and (butstatD & (1<<0)) == 0 and (prevbutstatD & (1<<0)) >  0 ) keypressed  = pinD0;
    if ( pinD0!=nokey and (butstatD & (1<<0)) >  0 and (prevbutstatD & (1<<0)) == 0 ) keyreleased = pinD0;
}`

Comment: In your edited code, shouldn't `keyreleased` be declared outside of `loop()`?

Comment: In your initial text, what does "keypressed = nokey_fir, keyrelesed = nokey_sec" refer to? Is that the initial state? During the key press sequences, why does keyreleased get set to nokey_sec when the previous key pressed was nokey_fir?

Comment: @IanAbbott Corrected again.

Comment: If anything, you don't have to use the "lastkey" variable.

Comment: As a quirk of English, note that "depressed" means the same as "pressed" in this English context; i.e. "He pressed a button." means the same as "He depressed a button." If you wrote "unpressed" I would interpret that to mean the same as "released", although "unpressed" is not commonly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an extra variable: `currentKey`:

```
void loop() {
  int analogVal = analogRead(A0);               //read analog voltage value from pin A0
  byte currentKey = nokey;

  if (analogVal < 325) currentKey = instrkey; //Correspondence of value and variable
  if (analogVal < 300) currentKey  = keyB4;
  if (analogVal < 275) currentKey  = keyA4s;
  if (analogVal < 250) currentKey  = keyA4;
  if (analogVal < 225) currentKey  = keyG4s;
  if (analogVal < 200) currentKey  = keyG4;
  if (analogVal < 175) currentKey  = keyF4s;
  if (analogVal < 150) currentKey  = keyF4;
  if (analogVal < 125) currentKey  = keyE4;
  if (analogVal < 100) currentKey  = keyD4s;
  if (analogVal < 75) currentKey  = keyD4;
  if (analogVal < 50) currentKey  = keyC4s;
  if (analogVal < 25) currentKey  = keyC4;
  if (analogVal > 1000) currentKey  = nokey;

  if (lastKey != currentKey) {  // Change detected
    keyreleased=lastKey;
    keypressed=currentKey;
    lastKey=currentKey;
  } else {  // No change detected
    keyreleased=nokey;
    keypressed=nokey;
  }
}
```

(You should also do something for `analogVal` in the range 326 to 1000. **EDIT: OP says there will be no such values.**)

The `keypressed`, `keyreleased` and `lastKey` variables are all initialized to `nokey` before the first update cycle.

The function `loop()` is called during each update cycle. It sets local variable `currentKey` to the current key press state. If a key is currently pressed (determined by a single analog voltage level, so only one key at a time can be pressed), `currentKey` gets set to the code for that key, otherwise it gets set to `nokey` to indicate that no key is currently pressed. The `lastKey` variable is assumed to be set to the value of `currentKey` from the previous update cycle, but will be `nokey` for the first update cycle.

The following conditions and actions can occur when `currentKey` is updated:

1. `lastKey == currentKey && currentKey == nokey` — no change; no key is pressed (i.e. *nokey* → *nokey*)

   - Set:

     ```
     keyreleased=nokey;
     keypressed=nokey;
     ```

     because there is no change.
2. `lastKey == currentKey && currentKey != nokey` — no change; previous key is still pressed (e.g. *keyX* → *keyX*)

   - Set:

     ```
     keyreleased=nokey;
     keypressed=nokey;
     ```

     because there is no change.
3. `lastKey != currentKey && lastKey == nokey` — change from no key pressed to some key pressed (e.g. *nokey* → *keyX*)

   - Set:

     ```
     keyreleased=lastKey;   /*=nokey*/
     keypressed=currentKey; /*=keyX*/
     ```

     because something has changed.
4. `lastKey != currentKey && currentKey == nokey` — change from some key pressed to no key pressed (e.g. *keyX* → *nokey*)

   - Set:

     ```
     keyreleased=lastKey;   /*=keyX*/
     keypressed=currentKey; /*=nokey*/
     ```

     because something has changed.
5. `lastKey != currentKey && lastKey != nokey && currentKey != nokey` — change from some key pressed to some other key pressed (e.g. *keyX* → *keyY*)

   - Set:

     ```
     keyreleased=lastKey;   /*=keyX*/
     keypressed=currentKey; /*=keyY*/;
     ```

     because something has changed.

As can be seen, the code for cases 1 and 2 (no change) can be merged together, and the code for cases 3, 4 and 5 (some change) can be merged together.

`lastKey` is then set to the value of `currentKey` ready for the next update cycle.

Comment: This range is not used at all. In my case there will be no such values.

Comment: I completely forgot to specify that 'lastkey' = 'keypressed'. I corrected my question